# firewalld rules that will block traffic from internet but allow internal traffic

Tags: firewalls

I want to block some ports access to the internet but still allow internal hosts to access the port with firewalld. There is another firewall between the internet and the host but I want to add a firewall on the host too.

Do I block the ports incoming and then add a whitelist rule to allow ports for the internal CIDR? I'm not sure how to do this with Firewalld.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewalld uses zones.  The default zone is `public`, but it also by default includes `home`, `work`, and `trusted`.

Traffic not explicitly assigned to any zone uses `public`.  You can list all the zones and their ports and services with `--list-all-zones`

1. Assign the local traffic to one of the non-public zones. (`--add-source` with a subnet address)  Trusted by default has all ports open.
2. If the ports are not already open on the zone you select, add them. (`--add-service` or `--add-port`)
3. Make sure the port is removed from public.  By default, public only has ssh open I think.

Comment: Are you saying that all the different zones are active all the time? I was under the impression that only the default zone was active.

Comment: `--list-all-zones` marks zones that are active (except the default public zone).  All zones are active that have traffic assigned to them.   I'm not suggesting all zones are active, I'm suggesting you pick one of those zones and *make* it active by assigning the local subnet to it.